# How do you get back to the original string from NSTextCheckingResult?

Tags: objective-c

I understand that a NSURL is returned on the NSTextCheckingResult, but how can you get back to the original string.  NSURL formats the url, unless there is a method on here that gets you back to the original url.

```
NSError *error = nil; 
NSDataDetector *detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:
                                (NSTextCheckingTypeLink | NSTextCheckingTypePhoneNumber)
                                                               error:&error];


  [detector enumerateMatchesInString:html 
        options:0 
        range:NSMakeRange(0, [html length]) 
        usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

           if (result.resultType == NSTextCheckingTypeLink) {
                 NSLog(@"original string is %@", ???);
           }

        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
       if (result.resultType == NSTextCheckingTypeLink) 
       {
           NSLog(@"original string is %@", 
               [result.URL isFileURL] ? [result.URL path] : [result.URL absoluteString]);
       }
```

Or get whatever you want to know about the URL.